# Why when using flex the style tag get the "style" too?

Tags: css, html, flexbox

when i create a html page with this code

```
     <style> 
          * { 
               display: flex; 
               justify-content:center; 
               align-items:center; 
          } 
     </style>
```

i get this ouput

[image]

Why is that ?

[I'm not searching for solution i'm asking for the reason why i get this output when using "display:flex" only (not when using other css props)]

Comment: Can you provide this in fiddle or add html code here.

Comment: lol, it just one line code. I don't think we need jsfiddle for that...

Comment: just create a html file and put the code on it.
in JSFiddle you can't add a style tag

Comment: @Leothelion I am asking him to reproduce this in fiddle.

Comment: Is this the code of the whole page, or is there more?

Comment: but i don't think it is possible in jsfiddle as one style tag and that's it.

Comment: @Leothelion It is possible I have created a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5c98xoky/

Comment: @LinkinTED yes that's all you need to understand the problem

Comment: If you remove `display: flex` it will work. https://jsfiddle.net/24fatsan/1/

Comment: @SrinivasPai, yes but then the output will be different as in local computer it shows different. And thanx for telling me that IMP thing..

Answer (score 1):

*Given that head and style by default are never displayed* when you create a html page with this code only

```
<style>
    * { 
       display: flex;
       justify-content:center;
       align-items:center;
    }
</style>
```

the browser will generate the following DOM structure

[image]

Since you have defined that style for all elements (through the star selector), then that rule is applied also to `head` and `style` elements, so they appear with the style you've defined

In order to prevent this behaviour you could apply that style only to the `body` and its descendents if this is your goal, e.g.

```
<style>
    body, body * { 
       display: flex;
       justify-content:center;
       align-items:center;
    }
</style>
```

or simply to all elements except the `head`

```
<style>
    :not(head) { 
       display: flex;
       justify-content:center;
       align-items:center;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Try
*{color:red}
or even
style{display:flex}

Comment: @ElheniMokhles I don't understand: if you apply a red color you will see that style in red, for the reason described above. What are you expecting instead?

Comment: I've just checked on my localhost and the color turns red

Comment: of course if you remove the display then head and style won't be displayed at all. I don't get your point. sorry.

Comment: So the answer is
because by default head and style don't have a display. Thank you :))

Answer (score 0):

Please remove `*` sign before css attributes.
if you want to apply style in all attribute you have to use
 `<style>`

```
<style>
    body *{ display: flex; 
            justify-content:center; 
            align-items:center; }

</style>
```

if you add css class and attribute in `.css` file you can use

```
*{ display: flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center;}
```

Comment: it's used to say that all HTML elements need to have this style ..
but what's happened even the style element have it

Answer (score 0):

The `*` selects all elements, including the `html`, `head`, `style`, `body` and all other tags... Somehow, there seems to be the problem. See this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yos36nwh/).

Solution is to only target all elements inside the body:

```
body * { 
     display: flex; 
     justify-content:center; 
     align-items:center; 
}
```

Comment: why when using style{dispaly:flex} we don't have the same thing ?

Comment: try the same code but in place of "*" use "style"
we exepect the same resulat, right?

Comment: Well, the problem is that the flex attribute also effect all elements like the head of the page. You probably only want to be the elements inside the body to be display flex, right? So, what is the problem with using `body * { ... }` instead of `* { ... }`??

Comment: @Linkin Ted, m big fan of your answer but this answer is totally wrong as after this, css wont work. try adding color and you will see its not affecting anything. If you will put , between body and * then it will work.Please test your answer and let me know if i am wrong. sorry for being rude.

Comment: I'm asking for the resean that's make this happening only when using flex

Comment: Because the flex attribute affects the head (and other) element... What more is there to need to know...

Comment: @LinkinTED, http://jsfiddle.net/yos36nwh/2/ check this one as if i will write text in under body only why its not working?

Comment: Because `body *` selects all the elements inside the body. If you want to affect the body aswell, use `body, body * { ... }`

Comment: as you said body * selects all the elements inside the body then why it din change the color of content of body without putting them into div or p but if i will use , between body and * then it will work.sorry if i did not get anything.

Comment: `*` selects all elements.  `body *` selects all elements *inside* the body.   `body, *` selects the body *and* all elements. `body, body *` selects the body *and* all elements *inside* the body.... Hope it's clear now.